# Bootstrap Tabbed Navigation glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some issues with a tabbed block on my website. I have a demo link at the foot of this.

Firstly when I click the tabs, they don't remain active after clicking. Also, I want to only show the tab content that has been clicked. Right now, it just lists all 5 divs. Help?

**HTML:**

**JS:**

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
            $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
        });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/czh8q2Le/

Comment: Is this what you wanted? https://jsfiddle.net/czh8q2Le/1/

Comment: Hey Nick - I think that's the original link I posted :)

Comment: Edit is perfect - thank you!!!! :) Was it just changes to the JS?

Comment: I'll post it as a solution explaining it. It was more just a change to your css

Comment: Also, please do add this as an Answer as it is correct and I'd like to reward you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a new class to your SCSS called `.show-tab`

```
.show-tab {
  display: block;
}
```

Also, you will want to add the following attribute to your `.tab-content`

```
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
```

This allows all your divs to be initially invisible, and then make them visible once you add the `.show-tab` class to the div.

Then in your HTML replace your current tag for your divs with `show-tab` like so (this makes it so the first div is initially shown)

```
<div class="tab-content show-tab" id="tab-pencil-pleat">
    1
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab-delivery">
    2
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab-eyelet">
    3
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab-tabtop">
    4
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab-wave">
    5
</div>
```

Finally, simply change your javascript so it changes the `show-tab` class, allowing you to add `.show-tab` to the divs you want to be shown and to remove `.show-tab` from the divs you don't wish to display:

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('show-tab');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('show-tab');
});
```

Hope this helps.
Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/czh8q2Le/1/